# How I write a python code for multiply each element in row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pandas

Here  is a data frame I wanted same output.
Please tell me how should I write  a python code to solve question...

DF

```
    A    B    C
1   1    2    3
2   1    3    5
3   1    1    1
```

And I need A output like

Answer:

```
      Multiplication
1         6
2        15
3        1
```

Comment: Use: `df.prod(axis = 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.prod` over `axis=1`

```
df.prod(axis=1)

1     6
2    15
3     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you vey much for your answer..
This worked